# Модальные окна в PHP цикле

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть такая задачка. У меня есть вывод новостей пользователей. Новости выводятся в цикле (**do-while**). Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "**Подробнее**" открывалось мод. окно с полной новостью и комментариями к этой новости, а также блоком для добавления комментариев. Т.е. я хочу узнать **javascript**, который будет открывать мод. окна по уникальному id новостей. Уникальный id новости создается автоматически в цикле. А как быть с **JS**, который будет открывать именно это окошечко этой новости не знаю.
Очень надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так.

```
$("a.full_post").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var elem = $("div#post");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/myajax.php",
        dataType: "text",
        type: "POST",
        data: {id:id},
        success: function(response) {
            elem.html(response);
        }
    });
    elem.dialog();
    return false;
});
```

Где `a.full_post` - ссылка вида.

```
<a href="#" class="full_post" id="id-статьи">Подробнее</a>
```

`$("div#post")` - див, в который будет загружаться текст статьи.

```
<div id="post"></div>
```

JS скрипт естественно надо обрамить **`$(document).ready(fn);`**

Comment: Да, я использую jquery-ui dialog, но как сделать так, чтобы открывалось это окошечко этой новости. Как я уже писал, новости эти выводятся в цикле и их на странице может быть больше ста штук. У них есть кнопка "Подробнее" с уникальным ID. Как доработать функцию JS вывода модальн окон?

Comment: Ссылкой `"Подробнее..."` передаете параметр ID-статьи в JS скрипт, который выполняет AJAX запрос на сервер, получает текст нужной статьи и вставляет его в `<div>`, на котором у вас висит `dialog()`.

Comment: Я чайник в JS. Поэтому не знаю как делаются такие простые вещи как принятие параметра ID. Можно подробно написать весь JS скрипт. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Огромоне Вам спасибо, все получилось. Теперь только остается доработать.

Comment: @Николай, если получилось, там слева от ответа есть галочка. Нажмите ее, если не трудно).

Comment: Почему то ширина окна не меняется, хотя в CSS все другие стили работают.